# vb.net how to check case of label.text i.e lower case, upper case

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

How to check caseing in label.text vb.net

I want to check wheather label text is in

upper case or  lowercase or  title case or  sentence case or Toggle case

got the solution for lower and upper

```
 if  char.isLower()=true then

 'my code

 endif

 if  char.isUpper() =true then

 'my code

 endif
```

title case or

sentence case or

Toggle case

still dnt knw how to check

Comment: What do u mean with: title, sentance and toggle case? Please give examples.

Comment: How to check caseing in label.text vb.net - this is sentence case   |||     hOW tO cHECK cASEING iN lABEL.tEXT vB.nET - this is toggle case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

isUpper and isLower apply to single characters within a string.  I think a better solution is to create a temporary string that is formatted the way you want it and return the comparison.

As an example (for ProperCase)

```
If String.Format(yourString, vbStrConv.ProperCase) = yourString then
    'your code for proper case
End If
```

With this, you should be able to get *most* of your comparisons going.  As for toggle case, you are going to have to write an algorithm that does the string conversion for you.  See http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/162540/Letter-Case-Conversion-Algorithms-Title-Case-Toggl for a fairly useful algorithm.